# Configure WCF to send requests in text/xml and recieve application/soap+xml responses

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I want to consume an external non-.NET **SOAP** service in a **.NET app**.
I'm able to create the client for the service using its WSDL via '**Add Service Reference**' in Visual Studio without any warnings or errors.
I've got the following auto-generated config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GenericTicketConnector_Service1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.112.34/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnector"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GenericTicketConnector_Service1"
        contract="Otrs.TicketConnector.GenericTicketConnector_Interface"
        name="GenericTicketConnector_endPoint1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Next, I write the common client code to test the communication between my client and the service:

```
    try
    {
        var client = new GenericTicketConnector_InterfaceClient();
        var ticketSearchRequest = new OTRS_TicketSearch
        {
            ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType6.UserLogin,
            Item = "root@localhost",
            Password = "root",
            TicketChangeTimeNewerMinutes = "600"
        };

        var ticketSearchResult = client.TicketSearch(ticketSearchRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

And during exexution of the `client.TicketSearch(ticketSearchRequest);`, I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException was caught
  Message=The content type application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 577 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><TicketSearchResponse xmlns="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/"><TicketID>981</TicketID><TicketID>980</TicketID><TicketID>979</TicketID><TicketID>978</TicketID><TicketID>977</TicketID></TicketSearchResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'.
```

AFAIK, this exception indicates that the binding is wrong.
The service expects requests with content type `text/xml` and this is why '**Add Service Reference**' used `basicHttpBinding`. But by some reason, the service response type is `application/soap+xml`, when the client expexts the same `text/xml` as the request type is.
I've tried `wsHttpBinding` and `webHttpBinding` binding types. But in these cases the service returns `<faultstring>Got no OperationType!</faultstring>`, i.e. these binding types aren't suitable for the service.

So my question is: **how to configure client binding to sent messages with content type `text/xml` and to consume responses in `application/soap+xml`?**

**UPDATE 1:**
After the @**YaronNaveh** suggestion with `<customBinding>`, the client is able to parse service response. But even if there is data in the respone, I'm getting `ticketSearchResult == null` without any exceptions.
Here is the service response:

```
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <TicketSearchResponse xmlns="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/">
         <TicketID>981</TicketID>
         <TicketID>980</TicketID>
         <TicketID>979</TicketID>
         <TicketID>978</TicketID>
      </TicketSearchResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3UmQQ8UvW3JaXV5OEVjRk1KSTA/edit?usp=sharing) is the WSDL I used to generate the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the service will be ok with application/soap+xml in the request too using this binding:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0">
    <textMessageEncoding MessageVersion="Soap12" />
    <httpTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

If not you need to write a [custom message encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486(v=vs.110).aspx). The encoder implementation could be exactly as the sample link. You would need to instruct it to accept any content type:

```
public override bool IsContentTypeSupported(string contentType)
{
    return true;
}
```

The sample config is already configured to send soap/xml in the request.

Comment: thanks for helping! I've tested with your binding and make sure that the service is ok with SOAP 1.2 requests. It returns a response containing data, but on the .NET client side I'm getting `ticketSearchResult` == null without any exceptions. What are the further ideas?

Comment: this seems like a new unrelated problem. please publish the response soap and the WSDL with the schemas.

Comment: I've updated the question with the service response and WSDL I used to generate the client.

Comment: set up a temporary WCF service from the same WSDL (here's one option to do it http://merill.net/2011/08/generating-a-mockstub-wcf-web-service-from-a-wsdl/). call this service from your client and see how the SOAP it returns is different from the one the real service returns. Most probably there is a different namespace on one of the response elements, or there is some wrapper element expected on the response. Might be possible to fix this with changes to the WSDL (on your side of course) or the proxy.

Comment: Alternatively you could try good old .Net 2 services ("add web reference") instead of WCF, they work better with certain XML flavours and you don't seem to need the WCF security. http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2008/10/interoperability-gotcha-visual-studio.html

Comment: Yaron, Thanks a lot! This is very usefull information.